# Efficient Algorithm for updating a pointer to the earliest pending work log

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

There's a DynamoDB table which holds records. This table has 1 row that's dedicated to just tracking the `nextPending` message. The partition key field has the value `nextPending` and it has a `messageId`. All other rows of the table contain messages. Each record has a `messageId` which is unique and has no gaps and is non-decreasing. At this point in time there are over 1M records in this table. The records indicate a piece of work. A service consumes this queue and processes each message one by one. After completely processing the message, it does two things. Firstly, it sets the status field of the record to a terminal state. Next, it updates the `nextPending` record with `messageId` = previous `messageId + 1`.

Now, we are attempting to make this service multi-threaded. Instead of processing messages one at a time, we'll have multiple threads that work on messages in parallel and these messages can be completed in random order.

I'm looking for an efficient and elegant algorithm for updating the `nextPending` field appropriately. Imagine nextPending currently has the value 101. Various threads in the service are working on messages between 101 and 110. Say, they complete in this order: 109, 105, 104, 108, 103, 102, 114, 101, .... We'd need to update nextPending to 105 after we see that 101 is done. Until 101 is done, we cannot update `nextPending` because 101 might fail and will need to be retried and as long as it is not done, `nextPending` should always point to the earliest pending message.

One algorithm maybe:

After completely processing the message, each thread does two things. Firstly, it sets the status field of the record to a terminal state. Next, it updates the `nextPending` record with the the earliest `messageId` that's pending at this point. But, this solution requires each thread to read several records from DynamoDB and check the status of the message. Also, several threads will now compete to conditionally update this one row in the table. That's also not something ideal.

Another algorithm maybe: 
Each thread shares a common rolling window of some sort which tracks all the completed messages. When a message is completed, a dedicated thread checks if it's `messageId` = `nextPending + 1`. If yes, we update `nextPending` to be the largest number in the current sequence of completed messages. In this method, we don't unnecessarily read from DynamoDB, we also don't have several threads racing against one another to do the same unit of work.

Any better ideas here?

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes. But, this solution requires us to read each subsequent record in the database to see what its status field is. That's not preferred. Let me clarify in the question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes, I agree that there should be a dedicated thread for the `nextPending` record. I would call that the Dispatch thread. And there should be a pool of Worker threads. The Dispatch thread assigns tasks to the Workers, and the Workers notify the Dispatch thread when they finish.

Comment: Yep, agreed. What's the best data structure for the Dispatch thread to use to track the set of completed messages?

Comment: I'd put the completed message IDs into a [min heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) (aka a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)).

Comment: Yep, a MinHeap would work nicely. So, every time we complete a message, add to the heap (time complexity - O(1)). We find-min and see if it is 1 greater than nextPending. If yes, delete-min (O(log n). Repeat until find-min is != nextPending + 1.

Comment: If the order of processing does not matter (you gave an example of unordered completion), why bother with this at all? Why not just batch it in parallel arbitrarily with retry logic?